# Decorate re-using another decorator's implementation

Tags: python, decorator, partial, code-reuse

I've implemented a `memoize` decorator, which allows to cache a function. The cache key includes the function arguments. Similarly the `cached` decorator caches a function, but ignores the arguments. Here is the code:

```
class ApplicationCache (Memcached):
```

The `make_key` method: *UltraJSON* delivers quickly a string, which *SHA512* hashes into a crisp hex digest:

```
    def make_key (self, *args, **kwargs):

        kwargs.update (dict (enumerate (args)))
        string = ujson.encode (sorted (kwargs.items ()))
        hashed = hashlib.sha512 (string)

        return hashed.hexdigest ()
```

The `memoize` decorator: Since Python 2.x sucks w.r.t. fully qualified function names, I simply force the user to deliver a reasonable `name`:

```
    def memoize (self, name, timeout=None):
        assert name

        def decorator (fn):
            @functools.wraps (fn)
            def decorated (*args, **kwargs):

                key = self.make_key (name, *args, **kwargs)
                cached = self.get (key)

                if cached is None:
                    cached = fn (*args, **kwargs)
                    self.set (key, cached, timeout=timeout)

                return cached
            return decorated
        return decorator
```

The `cached` decorator: It's almost a verbatim copy of `memoize` with the single exception where `make_key` ignores the arguments:

```
    def cached (self, name, timeout=None):
        assert name

        def decorator (fn):
            @functools.wraps (fn)
            def decorated (*args, **kwargs):

                key = self.make_key (name) ## no args!
                cached = self.get (key)

                if cached is None:
                    cached = fn (*args, **kwargs)
                    self.set (key, cached, timeout=timeout)

                return cached
            return decorated
        return decorator
```

Now, my problem with `cached` is, that it screams for re-factoring: It should use `memoize` and the idea would be to eliminate the arguments of `fn` (using `functools.partial` maybe?), like:

```
    def cached (self, name, timeout=None):

        ## Reuse the more general `memoize` to cache a function,
        ## but only based on its name (ignoring the arguments)
```

I'm actually not sure if I'm overdoing the DRY principle here, and if reuse is even possible, since the current implementation of `cached` ignores the arguments *only* while building the key (but obviously *not* while invoking the decorated function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd get rid of the `name` argument and provide the key function as an argument:

```
def memoize(self, timeout=None, keyfunc=self.make_key):
    ...
    key = keyfunc(function.__name__, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

`cache` will then just become:

```
def cache(self, timeout=None):
    return self.memoize(timeout, keyfunc=lambda f, *args, **kwargs: f.__name__)
```

Comment: Brilliant, working with decorators must have blinded me to this obvious solution. Thank you. ;D The gist is available here: https://gist.github.com/4417820

Comment: @hsk81: By the way, why do you use JSON to stringify the arguments? It might be better to just do `str()`, as that'll be faster and will work for objects that aren't serializable.

Comment: Thank you you're right, replaced `JSON.encode` with `unicode` (using session ID `sid` instead of session); updated gist is available at https://gist.github.com/4418107.